# Cookie is not set on the first visit

Tags: php, cookies

Though I have set the cookie using `setcookie`, why does it skip to the `else` part during the first time of execution/ first visit?

```
<?php
    setcookie("dan", "Sony", time()+60);
    if(isset($_COOKIE['dan']))
    {
        echo "Set";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Not yet!";
    }

?>
```

P.S: I know it is a naive question and gets downvoted but I don't find a better forum than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setcookie() merely arranges for the HTML headers emitted by the PHP script to contain the necessary "Set-Cookie:" header. The browser responds by storing the cookie and then regurgitating it on the next request to the site.

setcookie() does not set any variables inside the currently-executing script, which is why you're not seeing anything the first time through.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get value from `$_COOKIE` in the same request you do `setcookie`, you could get it begin from the next request.

**The first time you only tell the browser to set the cookie, at the time, there is no cookie data in the request header (which could get from `$_COOKIE`).**

Comment: How do i "tell the server" to send me a cookie via the header Set-Cookie for the first time? i am struggling with it,

Answer (score 0):

Set your cookies with javascript.

```
 function createCookie(name,days,value) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        } else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }

    function readCookie(name) { //cookie reader function
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }

    function eraseCookie(name) { //cookie eraser function
        createCookie(name,"",-1);
    }
            createCookie("test", 1, 1);
            var mycookie= readCookie("test");
            alert(mycookie);
```